# Remove all unused Slide Layout from my Master Slide from Powerpoint Presentation using OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentation

I'm currently working on editing my existing PowerPoint file (.pptx) using [OpenXML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).
Can I know how to remove all unused (unlinked) Slide Layouts from my PowerPoint presentation?

The reason for this is I want to reduce the PPTX file and I have 100+ unused layouts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with OpenXML SDK you need to parse all slides and/or slide layouts and check relationships between them. On the other hand, this can be easily done with [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/):

```cs
using var presentation = new Presentation("input.pptx");
presentation.LayoutSlides.RemoveUnused();
presentation.Save("output.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.